Magento 2 : Trigger Not Fire After Create Cart Rule
I use magento 2.4.6-p5.
I try to install rabbitmq for my server but my store not run trigger when I create cart rule but when I deleted it auto run the trigger, and not sent email after that, then I try to removed rabbitmq but my store have still have this error, I try to remove and reinstall cron, move to another server but the error still not fixed.
Please help.

Anyone Help ,
please
